# SingleValueEvent Showing null

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Query sqlite = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
sqlite.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Message")) {
                    String msg = dataSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString();
                    String from = dataSnapshot.child("From").getValue().toString();
                    String time = dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue().toString();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NULLLL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Database

[image]

This is the most basic thing in the database. I have never got a problem with `childEvent` or `valueEvent` and i want  a single event for now and I'm not able to fetch.

There is no error because i have put an if statement and it shows toast as **null** which means `dataSnapshot` doesn't have a child named messages but  it's right there. I tried putting a for loop too, but didn't work

Comment: You're missing to add `child(UID)` as looking from your database, try it once.

Comment: But thats the push ID @JeelVankhede

Comment: According to your database query, there's no child added for your UID, so database will directly reference to UID child and is why your Message is null.

Comment: But i wont know the UID right? so how can i fetch it. Usually the database just goes through it but why isnt it happening now @JeelVankhede

Comment: If you try to hardcode those ids (`MessageSenderId` and `MessageRecieverId`) do you get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given the full reference. There is a list of push keys and you have to use a foreach loop.

```
Query sqlite = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
sqlite.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

for (DataSnapshot vinSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (vinSnapshot .hasChild("Message")) {
                    String msg = dataSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString();
                    String from = dataSnapshot.child("From").getValue().toString();
                    String time = dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue().toString();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NULLLL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
```

Or you can store all data into ArrayList then perform your task.